# Rollback previous multiple services with mule service orchestration

Tags: mule

Our system compose of 10 subsystems, and explore services by socket, http/xml, http/protobuff and ERP service, I am looking for a framework to manage the system integration, and research Mule3 for several days. I know mule service orchestration can make multiple call to different remote service in a flow, however i am wondering whether Mule can cancel previous services automatically, for example i want to call 4 remote services, so in mule3 i define a flow and call those 4 services in turn.

1. call service#1
2. call service#2
3. call service#3
4. call service#4

Now if service#4 failed, can Mule3 automatically call, for example

1. call cancelService#1
2. call cancelService#2
3. call cancelService#3

to cancel those 3 successful services. For the same reason, if service#3 failed, I want to call cancelService#1 and cancelService#2. Can mule3 help to handle this?

Besides can Mule3 pass the response of previous service as argument to next service? for example pass the result of service#1 to service#2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [compensating pattern](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/compensating_service_transaction) and it works well with transports not transactional by design (i.e. http)

Probably the best way to achieve this would be by incapsulating your compensating logic into a [catch exception strategy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Catch+Exception+Strategy) and with a [choice router](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice), evaluate the exception and decide what services need to be compensated.

A more verbose option would be to store into the session what WS have already been invoked and use that property to chose what compensation needs to be done. I would not recommend this approach, unless you could not determine what WS have failed from the exception

Comment: Thanks. Could you pls tell me where can i find a sample code?

Comment: Seem mule3 doesn't have built-in support to compensation service transaction, like what introduced in this post https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CompensatingTransactionsWhenACIDIsTooMuch?_sscc=t

Comment: That is correct, you need to implement the compensating logic yourself, depending on your needs.